# How does the following Assembly language code run?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I know nothing about assembly, but I am given an assignment of this.

Please tell me how does the following code run? I mean the steps or procedures.

```
TITLE MASM Template (main.asm)

; Description: 
;
; Revision date:f

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
counter dword 1;
instruct1 BYTE"How many line are required?: ",0 ;give instruction to user to give the input
answer BYTE"Answer:",0

newline BYTE 0Dh, 0Ah

sum BYTE 0

.code
main PROC
mov edx,OFFSET instruct1 ;move instruct1 to edx
call WriteString
call readint;
mov ecx,eax; move ecx to eax
L1:

push ecx;
mov ecx,counter
L2:
mov al,'*';add '*' into al
call writechar;


loop l2;
pop ecx;
inc counter;
call crlf;
loop l1;



exit
main ENDP

end main
```

Comment: Have a guess at what `call WriteString` and `call readint` do, then look at the strings and comments, and maybe work back from there ?

Comment: Could u pls explain me what are `call WriteString` and `call readint`? tq

Comment: What it *does* is print a square of `*` characters. So if the user enters 2, it will print two rows of `**`. If the user enters 4, it will print 4 rows of `****`. If you're asking "how does it work?", you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: `WriteString` and `ReadInt` are functions that most likely are provided in the include file, "Irvine32.inc", which is included at the top of the file. I suspect that `WriteString` writes a string to the console, and `ReadInt` reads a number that the user inputs from the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code prints a prompt and inputs a number. It then prints that number of lines of stars. On the first line is 1 star, the second line 2 stars, and so on. I have annotated the code to make it more clear.

The code does this with two nested loops. The `ecx` register is used for both loops: as a counter for the stars on each line, and for the line count. That is why `ecx` is pushed and popped, so it can have another count in the inner loop.

```
TITLE MASM Template (main.asm)      ;used for listings etc.

; Description: 
;
; Revision date:f

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc                ;include another code file

.data                               ;data segment

counter dword 1                     ;characters per line
instruct1 BYTE"How many line are required?: ",0
answer BYTE"Answer:",0              ;irrelevant to this code
newline BYTE 0Dh, 0Ah               ;used by crlf
sum BYTE 0                          ;irrelevant to this code

.code                               ;code segment

    main PROC                       ;declare code block

    mov edx,OFFSET instruct1        ;message pointer
    call WriteString                ;display message
    call readint                    ;input an integer
    mov ecx,eax                     ;move input to line loop register
L1:
    push ecx                        ;save line count register
    mov ecx,counter                 ;load character counter
L2:
    mov al,'*'                      ;the char we wish to print
    call writechar                  ;output one char
    loop L2                         ;next character (count in cx)
    pop ecx                         ;restore the line counter
    inc counter                     ;increment characters per line
    call crlf                       ;print the newline defined above
    loop L1                         ;next line (count in cx)

    exit                            ;return to OS
    main ENDP                       ;end code block
    end main                        ;end of code file
```

If the input is 3, the output will be:

```
*
**
***
```

As an aside, I would criticise the author of the code for the following line, for two reasons.

```
mov ecx,eax     ; move ecx to eax
```

Reason 1. The comment is back to front; move the returned value `eax` to `ecx` for the line counter

Reason 2: Never use a comment to explain what an instruction does, you can RTM for that. Use comments for added value, to make it clear what the purpose is.